# Throw alert on page for Exception without page reload or repaint

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am submitting a form, once the validation is completed the fields will insert the data into a table.  If the insert returns with a 1062 (duplicate Key exception), I want to alert the user that they need to modify the field (literally return alert("Name Already Exists, please enter a new one");).

I have no problem redirecting pages on error, but I don't actually want the page to reload/repaint, just for the alert to appear.

Code for the SQL Exception

```
} catch(SQLException e){
   String errorCode = Integer.toString(e.getErrorCode());
   throw new FacesException(errorCode, e);
}
```

In the calling method, I am returning the actionstatus as being "duplicate" for this specific scenario, I am sending it to a xhtml page that simply contains the script with the alert, but because this is in the faces-config navigation, its redirecting the page instead of returning the response and simply displaying the alert.

Comment: Have you tried showing that error to the user with the `<p:message>` component ? I think it might serve you well in this case.

Comment: Are you using Ajax for your method call?

Comment: Alert? This isn't 1990 anymore. Why not just add a faces message?

Comment: Yeah, I will be answering this with the p:message, not sure why I wasn't doing that to begin with.
@BalusC - I 100% agree with you on this, requirements aren't always my call.

Answer (score 0):

In the calling methods catch statement

adding:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("This promotion name already exists.");
facesContext.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
```

In the original .xhtml page adding:

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
```

Comment: The below works fine.  However some of my previously rendered fields are not being rendered after the error.   I am getting a "Cannot format given Object as a Date" error, even though nothing has changed.  It only breaks when it tries to render, not in the java itself.

Comment: `Calendar input = new Calendar();
SimpleDateFormat dbFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String defaultDate = displayFormat.format(dbFormat.parse(defaultVal));
Date date = new Date();
date = displayFormat.parse(defaultDate);`